# Spring Security : Multiple HTTP Config not working

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring Security and I have a use case where I want different login pages and different set of URLs to be secured.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ProviderSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('BASE_USER')")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/admin/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
                .failureUrl("/admin/login?error=true").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
            .csrf()                    
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");            
    }
}


@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class ConsumerSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/consumer/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/consumer/**").access("hasRole('BASE_USER')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/consumer/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/consumer/home")
                .failureUrl("/consumer/login?error=true").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf()                
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }
}
```

These classes are inner classes of another class `MultipleHttpSecurityConfig` that has annotation `@EnableWebSecurity`.

The security for `admin/**` is working fine, but none of the `consumer/**` pages are secured, no redirection is happening for login page. I've searched for other answers but none worked.

Answer (score 33):

Look at the [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity):

> ```
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
>   @Autowired
>   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { 1
>       auth
>           .inMemoryAuthentication()
>               .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
>               .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
>   }
>
>   @Configuration
>   @Order(1)                                                        2
>   public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>           http
>               .antMatcher("/api/**")                               3
>               .authorizeRequests()
>                   .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
>                   .and()
>               .httpBasic();
>       }
>   }    
>
>   @Configuration                                                   4
>   public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>       @Override
>       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>           http
>               .authorizeRequests()
>                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
>                   .and()
>               .formLogin();
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> 1 Configure Authentication as normal
>
> 2 Create an instance of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that contains `@Order` to specify which `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` should be considered first.
>
> 3 The `http.antMatcher` states that this `HttpSecurity` will only be applicable to URLs that start with `/api/`
>
> 4 Create another instance of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. If the URL does not start with `/api/` this configuration will be used. This configuration is considered after `ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` since it has an `@Order` value after `1` (no `@Order` defaults to last).

Your second configuration is not used, because your first configuration matches `/**` (no `antMatcher` configured). And your first configuration restricts only `/admin/**`, all other URLs are permitted by default.

Comment: In other words, you can specify multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s which are considered in order by priority specified in `@Order` annotation. **First one that matches the** `.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/matcher/**")` **is used and others are discarded**. ie, `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s don't stack.

Answer (score 28):

Your first `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`'s

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
```

matches all the URLs, limit it to only URLs start with `/admin` by using `antMatcher`:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ProviderSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/admin/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('BASE_USER')")
                .and()

                ...
```