# Spring Security, Why second WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is not working?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

Update:

Adding `.antMatcher("/admin/**")` in the first WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter makes it work now, why is that?

now configure method of first WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is:

```
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/admin/**")                 // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<--- newly added
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADM")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/admin/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }
```

---

My site divides into 2 parts, one for user and another for manager, so I configured two WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters in my web app for each of them.

like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig  {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ManagerSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private ManagerDetailsService managerDetailsService;

        //allow access to static resouces
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/pc/css/**", "/pc/js/**", "/pc/img/**");
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/mobile/css/**", "/mobile/js/**", "/mobile/img/**");
        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADM")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/admin/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .userDetailsService(managerDetailsService);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class UserLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private WeUserDetailsService weUserDetailsService;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/user/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();

            http.addFilterBefore(new WeAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(weUserDetailsService);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the second WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is not working, if I enter: /admin into browser, it will take me to the /admin/login as expected,

while if I enter /user, it will directly go the action in controller, by passed the security filter.

why is that?

Comment: ref to : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33608459/404145, almost the same problem, also the official link maybe useful: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is first WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's

```
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
```

This will match all the urls, makes the second UserLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter useless, adding antMatcher can help limit the urls it can match, that's why adding 
`.antMatcher("/admin/**")` can work.