# How to secure spring Boot API with API key and secret

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to secure the Spring boot API end points. I would want to pass only api key and secret as part of the header to call the API. I tried this code posted in this link. but getting access denied while calling the api with Authorization in header. [Securing Spring Boot API with API key and secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446708/securing-spring-boot-api-with-api-key-and-secret)
I would like to know what i should pass as part of the header, so that i can get successful response from the API
I did the below steps:
I added the below entry in the application.properties

```
myapp.http.auth-token-header-name=samplekey
myapp.http.auth-token=abc123
```

And am trying to pass in the header as below
Authorization:myapp.http.auth-token-header-name=samplekey,myapp.http.auth-token=abc123

Comment: I am having this same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

With the example values you show, you need to provide the header with name "samplekey" and value "abc123".

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
samplekey: abc123
```

Or, if you put this in the configuration:

```
myapp.http.auth-token-header-name=X-API-KEY
myapp.http.auth-token=abc123
```

then you will need to provide the header with name "X-API-KEY" and value "abc123".

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
X-API-KEY: abc123
```