# Spring Boot: Is this secure? Api Key as RequestHeader vs Api Key via Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, api-key

Question: is my implementation secure (by API Key standards) OR as secure as using `Spring Boot Security`?

I have produced a `Spring Boot` API, but rather than using `Spring Boot` Security to implement Api Key security, I have written my own API key implementation. The API Key is passed as a `@RequestHeader` in each 'secured' request (see `/booking/cancel` below).

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/booking/cancel",
        consumes = { "application/json" },
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> cancelOrder(@RequestBody Cancellation cancellation, 
                                       @RequestHeader String apiKey) {

        if(apiKey == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }

        long bookingProviderId;
        try {
            bookingProviderId = bookingService.getIdFromApiKey(apiKey);
            if (bookingProviderId < 0) {
                return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            }
        } catch (ApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        //More code here...
}
```

**Service layer:**

The `getIdFromApiKey` function exists in my service layer and calls the Dao object. It returns a long (Id) which I can subsequently use to manage access in the controller (e.g. prevent a user from cancelling someone else's order).

```
public long getIdFromApiKey(String apiKey) throws ApplicationException {
    return apiKeyDao.selectId(apiKey);
}
```

**Dao Layer:**

```
public long getApiKey (String apiKey) throws DataAccessException {

    BookingProvider bp = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM BookingProvider WHERE apiKey = ?", BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(BookingProvider.class), apiKey);

    if(bp == null)
        return -1;
    else
        return bp.getId();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Late answer*: The approach behind your code is good, but you don't need to write so much code. It is better to configure this in one place with `Spring Security`. It will allow to add security only on your controllers as their are the entry point of your application. See this link for more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446708/securing-spring-boot-api-with-api-key-and-secret/72498590#72498590) and below is the code I am using:

**application.yml**

```
application:
  http:
    authentication:
      header-name: X-API-KEY-TEST
      api-key: X-API-KEY-VALUE-TEST
```

**ApiKeyProperties.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.http.authentication")
public class ApiKeyProperties {

    private String headerName;
    private String apiKey;
}
```

**ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
public class ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

    private final String headerName;

    public ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter(String headerName) {
        this.headerName = headerName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader(headerName);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**ApiSecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApiSecurityConfiguration {

    private final ApiKeyProperties apiKeyProperties;

    @Autowired
    public ApiSecurityConfiguration(ApiKeyProperties apiKeyProperties) {
        this.apiKeyProperties = apiKeyProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        var filter = new ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter(apiKeyProperties.getHeaderName());
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authentication -> {
            var principal = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (!apiKeyProperties.getApiKey().equals(principal)) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException("The API key was not found or not the expected value");
            }
            authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
            return authentication;
        });
        security.antMatcher("/**")
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .addFilter(filter)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        return security.build();
    }
}
```

**Postman**

[image]