# How to fix Spring authorizeRequests is deprecated?

Tags: java, spring

Spring is updated, says authorizeRequests is deprecated, antMatchers removed. Can someone show how SpringSecurity should looks like rn?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(PersonDetailsService personDetailsService) {
        this.personDetailsService = personDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/, /login, /signup, /logout").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/user").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/user").failureUrl("/login?error");
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Read the documentation, stackoverflow, etc. didn't find the solution.

Comment: One of the worst things in java - that the `@Deprecated` annotation doesn't mandate a description field or property describing what to use instead.

Answer (score 97):

You can use `authorizeHttpRequests` instead of `authorizeRequests` and `requestMatchers` instead of `antMatchers`.

For example:

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests()
  .requestMatchers("/authentication/**").permitAll()
  .requestMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
  .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Comment: Why can't I use antMatchers in this case?

Comment: @Tyler2P I have the same issue. How can I fix it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75709884/spring-integration-test-security-throws-403-forbidden-even-if-it-is-defined-t

Comment: @SantaMonica antMatchers() has been replaced with requestMatchers() in Spring Boot 3.

Comment: **`authorizeHttpRequests()` is also deprecated**, see [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests())

Comment: @MarcoLackovic yeah but only since Spring Boot 3.1, it wasn't yet in 3.0. Bit of a quick deprecation.

Answer (score 25):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74611324/144578) of [@Tyler2P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14267427/tyler2p) works well for Spring Boot 3.0 but in Spring Boot 3.1 authorizeHttpRequests() is already deprecated in favor of a different API.

It now should be

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
  .requestMatchers("/authentication/**").permitAll()
  .requestMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
  .anyRequest().authenticated());
```

This is also mentioned in the migration guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html

Also note that in later Spring Boot 3.1 the intermediate method `authorizeRequests` with lambda is also deprecated in favor of `authorizeHttpRequests`, however this does change functionality. For one, our custom authentication providers aren't called anymore so we have not been able to migrate yet.

Comment: There is an extra dot in this code: 
authz..requestMatchers

Comment: it doesn't let me run the app on local. Getting localhost:8080 is not authorised error

Answer (score 5):

For Spring Boot 3.1.0 my migration `filterChain(HttpSecurity http)` sample:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher("/api/**").authorizeHttpRequests(rmr -> rmr
            .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole(Role.ADMIN.name())
            .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
    ).httpBasic(httpbc -> httpbc
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
    ).sessionManagement(smc -> smc
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    ).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    return http.build();
}
```

Sample code could be found at https://github.com/JavaOPs/bootjava/tree/patched

Comment: please share the full code `authenticationEntryPoint` is not found

Comment: Have a look at e.g. https://github.com/JavaOPs/bootjava/blob/patched/src/main/java/ru/javaops/bootjava/config/RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

Answer (score 2):

This Code is working fine for me. I am using the Spring Tool Suite 4 (latest Version).

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(getUserDetailsService());
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    
    return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 
    http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/Admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
    .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll().and().formLogin().and().csrf().disable();
            
    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [*documentation*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)), you can use [`authorizeHttpRequests()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests(org.springframework.security.config.Customizer)):

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) ->
        authorizeHttpRequests
                .requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for Spring Boot 3.1.x
update your code accordingly

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.requestMatchers("/api").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/**")
                                .authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }
```