# Spring Integration Test -> Security throws 403 Forbidden even if it is defined to allow in SecurityChain

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I have a problem to test register through Integration Test in Spring Boot.

I use Spring Boot 3.

Here is the `SecurityFilterChain` bean defined in Security Config

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
  httpSecurity
    .cors()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(handler).and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/admin/register")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
    
  httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

Here is the relevant part of register user test shown

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/admin/register")
  .contentType("application/json")
  .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(registerRequest)))
```

I get 403 Forbidden. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it's only the test that is failing and that the end-point is working properly in the actual app.

In that case you need to make sure that the `SecurityFilterChain` bean is contained in the test context, otherwise you get the auto-configured Spring Security beans in any `WebMvcTest` which forbid access to any end-point by default.

Assuming that you're exposing the `SecurityFilterChain` from a configuration named `WebSecurityConfig`, you need to add the line

```
@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class)
```

on the test class where you most likely used `@WebMvcTest`.

I've made a lot of assumptions here. If these assumptions are wrong and this answer doesn't help you, please provide more details in your question.