# Spring Security Configuration update for Springboot Version 3.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-security

I am updating from Springboot 2.7.x to 3.1.x version and noticed that there is a change to the Security configuration.
I followed the steps provided in the [Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration) and facing issue converting below configuration to the latest that is supported in Springboot 3.1.x.

Could someone please help with the new configuration.

Facing issue rewriting below:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS).and().exceptionHandling()
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS).and()
            .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(AuthenticationEntryPoint);
  }
```

Full code:

```
package test.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
import static org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/public/**/**"));
    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);
    private final AuthenticationEntryPoint AuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    private static AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(FORBIDDEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/", "/csrf", "/configuration/ui", "/webjars/**", "/actuator", "/actuator/*");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS).and().exceptionHandling()
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS).and()
                .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(AuthenticationEntryPoint);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("userName").password(passwordEncoder.encode("passWord")).roles("Application");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Also tried solutions provided in the link: https://www.bezkoder.com/websecurityconfigureradapter-deprecated-spring-boot/

Answer (score 4):

From Spring Security 6 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter was deprecated, and you need to have same little changes, for more details how to change [check it](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) and [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)

And about your problem what you have with:

`protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception`

You should change it to:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement(sessionAuthenticationStrategy ->
        sessionAuthenticationStrategy.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    http.exceptionHandling(eH -> eH.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
        forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS
    ));
    http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(request ->{
      request.anyRequest().authenticated();
    });
    http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
    
    return http.build();
  };
```

Comment: Thank you. Solution is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to declare `authenticationEntryPoint` at

```
.httpBasic(hbc -> hbc.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint))
```

See [How to fix Spring authorizeRequests is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76538979/548473)

Answer (score 0):

```
SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    log.debug("Bearer SecurityConfig initialized.");
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                    .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .exceptionHandling(
                     ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
            .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

    // Add a filter to log the request-response of every request
    http.addFilterBefore(loggingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();

}
```