# Spring Security : Falls back to formLogin on authentication error

Tags: spring, spring-security

I tried to implement a SecurityConfig similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33608459 and https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

I want my API (`/rest/**`) to be secured by HttpBasic, and other requests via FormLogin.
This works well... as long as I provide the correct credentials to HttpBasic.

If I provide **correct** credentials - it response with normal answer.
If I provide **no** credentials - it responds with a **`401 Unauthorized`** - perfect!
If I provide **wrong** credentials - it responds with a **`302 Found`** with **`Location: /login`**

The last part is what I don't want - I also want a **401 Unauthorized** on wrong credentials.

#### Example Requests:

> **`http http://localhost:8081/rest/`**
>   *`HTTP/1.1 401` `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"`*
>   **`http -a correct:password http://localhost:8081/rest/some/api/`**
>   *`HTTP/1.1 200`*
>   **`http -a wrong:password http://localhost:8081/rest/some/api/`**
>   *`HTTP/1.1 302` `Location: http://hive.local:8081/login WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"`*

### Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class RestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  private AuthorizationProperties properties;

  @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http.antMatcher("/rest/**")
      .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole("API").and()
      .httpBasic()
        .realmName(properties.getRealm()).and()
      .formLogin().disable()
      .csrf().disable();
    // @formatter:on
  }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class FrontendSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/app/**", "/webjars/**", "/static/**", "/js/**");
  }

  @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER").and()
      .formLogin();
    // @formatter:on
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you try without `.formLogin().disable()`. If that not works, please add following to your configuration: `.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint())`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried both suggestions, and still get a redirect to the login page on wrong password.

Comment: so sad to see that there is no answer, I am having exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bring some light into this.

The redirect to form login after a failed basic auth request is cause by the dispatcher servlet trying to redirect to the URL `/error` after failing to validate the credentials.

To get the appropriate error response you need to add `/error` to the `antMatchers` that are ignored in your web security config.