# How to use different AuthenticationProvider for filter SPRING SECURITY

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

In my security layer I'm using two filters: AjaxAuthenticationFilter and JWTAuthenticationFilter (both of them extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter). For first one i want to use only oAjaxAuhtenticationProvider, and for second one only JwtAuthenticationProvider.

This is main reason of my problem i can't separate them (authenticationProviders).

I've tried this code, but doesn't work:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_HEADER_NAME = "Authorization";
    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_URL = "/api/auth/login";
    public static final String REFRESH_TOKEN_URL = "/api/auth/token";
    public static final String API_ROOT_URL = "/api/**";


    @Autowired private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired private AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
    @Autowired private AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;
    @Autowired private AjaxAuthenticationProvider ajaxAuthenticationProvider;
    @Autowired private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    protected AjaxLoginProcessingFilter buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter(String loginEntryPoint) throws Exception {
        AjaxLoginProcessingFilter filter = 
                new AjaxLoginProcessingFilter(loginEntryPoint, successHandler, failureHandler, objectMapper);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return filter;
    }

    protected JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(List<String> pathsToSkip, String pattern) {
        SkipPathRequestMatcher matcher = new SkipPathRequestMatcher(pathsToSkip, pattern);
        JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = 
                new JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(failureHandler, matcher);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        List<String> permitAllEndpointsList = Arrays.asList(
            AUTHENTICATION_URL,
            REFRESH_TOKEN_URL,
            "/console"
        );

        http.
            csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)

        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(permitAllEndpointsList.toArray(new String[permitAllEndpointsList.size()]))
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(API_ROOT_URL).authenticated(); 
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class AjaxWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter(AUTHENTICATION_URL), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationProvider(ajaxAuthenticationProvider);

        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class JwtWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            List<String> permitAllEndpointsList = Arrays.asList(
                    AUTHENTICATION_URL,
                    REFRESH_TOKEN_URL,
                    "/console"
                );

            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(permitAllEndpointsList, API_ROOT_URL),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603156/spring-security-multiple-http-config-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. My code was completely wrong. Wrong anotations and approach.

I solved my problem passing proper authManager to target configuration (only conspect):

```
 @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class AjaxWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            auth.authenticationProvider(ajaxAuthenticationProvider);
        }

    }

@Configuration
public class JwtWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
       }
}
```

In configuration with order(1), I have to define antMacher mandatory:

```
.and()
                    .antMatcher("/api/auth/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(AUTHENTICATION_URL)
                    .permitAll()
```

And in the last configuration I have to define antMatchers for "/**"

```
.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
```

Final Result:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class  WebSecurityConfig {

    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_HEADER_NAME = "Authorization";
    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_URL = "/api/auth/login";
    public static final String REFRESH_TOKEN_URL = "/api/auth/token";
    public static final String API_ROOT_URL = "/api/**";


    @Autowired private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired private AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
    @Autowired private AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;
    @Autowired private AjaxAuthenticationProvider ajaxAuthenticationProvider;
    @Autowired private JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    protected  AjaxLoginProcessingFilter buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter(String loginEntryPoint,
            AuthenticationManager  authManager) throws Exception {
        AjaxLoginProcessingFilter filter = 
                new AjaxLoginProcessingFilter(loginEntryPoint, successHandler, failureHandler, objectMapper);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        return filter;
    }

    protected JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(String urlForFilter,
            AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        //SkipPathRequestMatcher matcher = new SkipPathRequestMatcher(pathsToSkip, pattern);
        JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = 
                new JwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(failureHandler, urlForFilter);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        return filter;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class AjaxWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            auth.authenticationProvider(ajaxAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

                http.
                    csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)

                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

                .and()
                    .antMatcher("/api/auth/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(AUTHENTICATION_URL)
                    .permitAll()


                .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter(AUTHENTICATION_URL, super.authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .authenticationProvider(ajaxAuthenticationProvider);

        }

    }

    @Configuration
    public class JwtWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            auth.authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()

                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(API_ROOT_URL, super.authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationProvider(jwtAuthenticationProvider);

        }

    }

}
```