# Multiple login URL Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to add an other URL to log in my application for a mobile device. Because I want a custom response from server for mobile application. For example, I don't want an HTML in response but only code error.

My problem is my second URL for login: `/loginMobile` return code 405.

My code:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/chat/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/service/boite_idee_note/**", "/service/atelier_vote/**", "/service/equipe/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
                    .antMatchers("/", "/Repository/**", "/uploadFile", "/uploadPdf", "/uploadLogo","/upload_nouveau_venu", "/service/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .csrf()
                    .ignoringAntMatchers("/chat/**")
                    .csrfTokenRepository(this.csrfTokenRepository());
        }

        /**
         * @return
         */
        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        } 
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebSecurityConfigAppMobile extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/loginMobile")
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(this.csrfTokenRepository());
        }

        /**
         * @return
         */
        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security : Multiple HTTP Config not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603156/spring-security-multiple-http-config-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

.authorizeRequests()

Was catching all requests so my request did'nt go in second Adapter.

Thx for help :)