# Spring Security - Filter Ordering and Multiple HttpSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, filter

I want  two diffrent http configurations to come in depending on the url i am entering. For example, when i type in "localhost:8080/HQ/test_web" i want this configuration to come in.

```
 @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class FirstWaveFilters extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/HQ/test_web/**").anonymous().and().addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        }
    }
```

But, if its anything else, i want this configuration to come in:

```
@Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class SecondWaveFilters extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()

                    .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()



                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()

                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                    // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

            http.csrf().disable();
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }
    }
```

I have them set up in the same class as the Spring Security doc suggested:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class FirstWaveFilters extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/HQ/test_web/**").anonymous().and().addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        }
    }
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class SecondWaveFilters extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()

                    .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()



                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()

                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                    // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

            http.csrf().disable();
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

But it does not seem to work. Whatever url i enter, only the CUSTOMFILTER() gets called, so only the first configuration. Basically what i am trying to achieve is, if the user enters the first url i want that customfilter() to be the filter the request has to go through, if its any other url, i want it to go the second configuration and the two filters defined there to be the ones the request must go through. Why is this not working ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security : Multiple HTTP Config not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603156/spring-security-multiple-http-config-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

`http.antMatcher(...)` - means, apply this `http` and all what is configured here when pattern in `antMatcher` is met.

`http.authorizeRequests()...` - defines your permissions, if user hit that endpoint he should has "ADMIN", "logged" etc.

---

In your `FirstWaveFilters` you have to start your `http` with `http.antMatcher()`:

```
http.antMatcher("/HQ/test_web/**");
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/HQ/test_web/**").anonymous()
   .and()
   .addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

If you are not add `http.antMatcher(...);` than that `http` will intercept all urls and `SecondWaveFilters` never will be reached.

`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/HQ/test_web/**").anonymous()` - means that any anonymous user may hit `/HQ/test_web/**`, but it doesn't say "apply `FirstWaveFilters` when `/HQ/test_web/**`" it just mean anyone who hists `/HQ/test_web/**` may be anonymous.