# Spring boot security - Google signin & Username based login - JWT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Is it possible to have regular Username - password-based authentication & Oauth2 Google sign-in in the same monolith application? Any knowledge sharing about how to achieve this would be really appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security : Multiple HTTP Config not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603156/spring-security-multiple-http-config-not-working)

Comment: use some ready auth server like keycloak https://www.keycloak.org/ as identity rpovider - it includes all types of auth - password, google - and works fine with spring security

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's common to allow user choose different methods to login

login is just give the client a token after verifing the credential it provided

you can implement login api for each sign in method, returning same token

Comment: for social login we have oath2 approach. But for regular username password we have basic usercredential approach. How to mix them both is my question.